# Opening a changelist in Perforce

Tags: perforce, changelist

In perforce, `changelist` seems to be an important component/concept. It is mentioned as "a basic unit of work in perforce" in it's document [introducing perforce](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/intro/intro.pdf). I understand that changelists are used to submit changes to the perforce server, and they are assigned integer id. However, I would like to understand how they are implemented. Are changelists ordinary human-readable text file? Can the be opened given the changelist number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "open" a changelist, run:

```
p4 change CHANGENO
```

This will give you the changelist formatted as a human-readable text file (a changelist specification).

On the back end changelists are stored in a database, so there is not an editable text file on the back end that looks like this; running commands like "p4 change" and "p4 describe" will generate it for you.

The most important aspect of a changelist is usually the file revisions it contains; you can use a changelist as a revision specifier for most Perforce commands.  For example:

```
p4 files @CHANGENO,CHANGENO
p4 diff2 path/...@CHANGE1 path/...@CHANGE2
```

et cetera.